# Get an attribute of a class with another attribute

Tags: java

I've got a fundamental problem.

There are several classes, extending another one ("Skill").
"Skill" contains some abstract methods like:

```
public abstract int getID();
public abstract String getName();
public abstract String getDescription();
```

and the subclasses:

```
@Override
public int getID()
{
    return 69;
}

@Override
public String getName()
{
    return "name";
}

@Override
public String getDescription()
{
    return "description";
}
```

Now, let's say i need to get the description of the subclass with the id "89".
Is there an easier way of doing this, than having a HashMap storing id->classname and then getting an object of the class by doing the following?:

```
Class cl = Class.forName(classname);
Object o = cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
Method m = cl.getMethod("getDescription");
return (String) m.invoke(o);
```

Comment: This is one big code smell. Why are you identifying classes like this at all?

Comment: It is indeed. Thats why i am asking for a better way. For example: a player get's a buff. later, i need to check, if the player still has the buff and i only have got the id. but thinking about it, i also could directly store the instance of the buff..

Comment: Read this: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, wherever you got that "89" from, there should be a place to store a little factory method that creates the matching instance without using reflection alltogether...

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer,YourObject> yourMap = new HashMap<Integer,YourObject>();
yourMap.put(89,new YourObject(89,"description","name"));
yourMap.put(69,new YourObject(69,"description1","name1"));
..

YourObject eight_nine = yourMap.get(89);
```

isn't this a good method to achieve what you need?